# Why Synapse Analytics chooses a much bigger table to broadcast when joining

Tags: azure-synapse

I have two table. table 1 is around 800 rows and the other table has 80.000.000 rows.

I make a simple join between the table. It really frustrates me that it keeps broadcasting the big table when joining, instead of the small one, causing serious performance problem.

Even if I use option such as "MERGE JOIN", it still broadcasts the big table. (I come from Spark background, and if I understand right, it should shuffle (to sort merge) instead of keeping broadcasting anything.)

The execution plan looks like this.

[image]

I never have such problem with such simple joins when working with Spark. Can somebody help me with this.

Comment: What are the underlying distributions (ROUND_ROBIN, HASH, REPLICATE) and index choices (CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE (the default), CLUSTERED INDEX, HEAP) on your tables?  Do you have any indexes, constraints (unique not enforced, primary key not enforced)?  Have you tried updating the statistics?

Comment: They are all heap and round robin distributed. It have some nonclustered columnstore index but I have tested deleting the index. I also have updated the statistics. The weird thing is that sometimes it gives a correct plan, but also sometimes it gives a crazy plan. But most of the time it gives the above plan. (when testing, I constantly flush all the cache plan and result after a test)

Comment: I will post what I call crazy plan tomorrow, hope you can help me interpret it. In sum it took me both broadcasting and shuffle operator for just one simple join, which really make me surprised.

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid data movement operators in execution plans you should set up your [table distribution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-tables-distribute) properly.  The best practice here would be to `REPLICATE` your smaller table and to `HASH` distribute your large table on a suitable column that provides good distribution.

Some sample DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE fact.yourBigTable (

    ...

)
WITH
(
    CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX,
    DISTRIBUTION = HASH( someColumn )
);


CREATE TABLE dim.yourSmallTable (

    ...

)
WITH
(
    CLUSTERED INDEX ( someColumn ),
    DISTRIBUTION = REPLICATE
);
```

Obviously you have to experiment with your workload and data to find the combination.  Generally I would say updating columnstore indexes isn't a great idea: consider CTAS or another alternative.

Comment: The problem is that the small table is not guaranteed to be small. For sometimes, it may be small, but for sometimes, It may be as large as the big one. (Big is more usual than small) That is why I want to rely on the automatic algorithm instead of preparing the table in advanced. And the about the update one, I understand you but it is the current way my (new) company is doing this, so for now I will just leave it as is.

Comment: So for small tables replicate them, for large tables, hash distribute them on the same hash key as your other table.

Comment: Well the thing is that it is not guaranteed to be small every time. I always think that modern map-reduce processor is always smart enough to choose the right algorithm....

Comment: One of the benefits of using a versatile platform like Azure Synapse Analytics is that you have more than one way to do things, so if you don't feel that your workload is performing well on dedicated SQL pools, you can try Spark Pools, which now supports Spark 3.x [link](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-synapse-analytics/apache-spark-3-0-support-in-azure-synapse-analytics/ba-p/2382605).  I'd be interested to see if you get different results.

Comment: It may be just that I am still new to Synapse Analytics, so that I still cannot unlock its full power. I just joined the new company with this Synapse 2 weeks ago. Actually I still want to have some new experience with the new one though....But still I have to say that there are too many things that surprise me. Do you know which factors will have influence on query plan and do they really matter?

Comment: Yeah it's all the things I mentioned about distribution, indexing, stats, constraints etc  It's still a cost-based optimizer under the hood so the best thing to do is give it as much information as possible.  For performance tuning you also need to consider current DWU, the resource class for your current user, concurrency and of course query design, so only a few things : )

Comment: Finally, I have found the reason why Synapse keep broadcasting the big table. The reason is: it must. Because I am updating the small table, so it must be in its place (because you need to update it), and then compare with everyrow from big table, if there is a match, the row will be update. If the database bring the small table out and broadcast, then how can it be updated? I need update, not just print it out. Now I understand why in distributed database world, data should be truncate and rewrite instead of update. In my previous job, I just follow but don't understand. For now, yeah!